# No application 'Realtime' for extension (default, 1234, 2)

Tags: asterisk

Asterisk 13.14.1

I connected the LDAP. With the help of RealTime I want to pull attributes from AD.

There is a connection to LDAP:

```
CLI> realtime show ldap status
Connected to 'ldap://192.168.1.*:389', baseDN dc=mydomen,dc=local with username cn=user,ou=group,dc=mydomen for 16 hours, 5 minutes, 39 seconds.
```

Tried to load function:

```
CLI> module load func_realtime.so
Unable to load module func_realtime.so
Command 'module load func_realtime.so' failed.
[Feb  8 09:08:23] WARNING[56072]: loader.c:1077 load_resource: Module 'func_realtime.so' already exists.
```

Registered in /etc/asterisk/modules.conf:

```
   [modules]
   autoload=yes
```

This is my extensions.conf
/etc/asterisk/extensions.conf

```
[default]
switch => Realtime/ldap@extensions
exten => _1234,1,NoOp(=== Start LDAP =====)
exten => _1234,n,Realtime(extensions|nomerUser|333|aprefix_)
exten => _1234,n,NoOp(=== ${aprefix_nameUser} ===)
```

This is my extconfig.conf
/etc/asterisk/extconfig.conf

```
   [ldap]
   extensions => ldap,"ou=group,dc=mydomen,dc=local",extensions
```

This is my res_ldap.conf
/etc/asterisk/res_ldap.conf

```
   [_general]
   host=192.168.1.*
   basedn=dc=mydomen,dc=local
   user=cn=user,ou=group,dc=mydomen,dc=local
   pass=*****
   [extensions]
   nomerUser = telephoneNumber
   nameUser = cn
```

I expect the RealTime function to return the AD attribute (cn - Full name). 
But when executing the script, it gives an error:

```
Executing [1234@default:1] NoOp("SIP/603-00000018", "=== Start LDAP =====") in new stack
[Feb  8 09:34:35] WARNING[56342][C-0000000d]: pbx.c:2864 pbx_extension_helper: No application 'Realtime' for extension (default, 1234, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your extconfig is WRONG.
This file used to make general mapping. It should have only one section "[settings]"

Also if you do mapping to extensions, that mean WHOLE extension files should be loaded as text file from source specified.

There are no application realtime in asterisk. Instead you have REALTIME function. So doesn't metter how you setuped it, message will be same. This message about no registered application.

Comment: Made one [settings] in **extconfig.conf**.  

Corrected file **extensions.conf**.  

`switch => Realtime/@extensions`  
`exten => _1234,1,NoOp(=== Запуск LDAP =====)`  
`exten => _1234,n,Realtime(extensions|nomerUser|333|aprefix_)`  
`exten => _1234,n,NoOp(=== ${aprefix_nameUser} ===)`  

The problem did not dare.  

---------------------  
How to use the RealTime function correctly in order to output information from LDAP in a script?

Comment: If you do switch realtime, it is not for use realtime function, it is for read WHOLE CONTEXT in special format from realtime source(like read config from file, but file in REALTIME).